# how to use pagination in frontend (Angular) when the limit is defined in the backend (NodeJS, TypeORM)?

Tags: html, node.js, angular, typescript, typeorm

I am new to Angular and NodeJS. I want to use pagination in my frontend listing, I have limited my entries in backend method and it is working fine. The. problem is i am unable to use it in my frontend code and am confused how to to achieve the same .

My backend code -->

```
//get all staff data
    static async getStaffData(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void> {
        try {
          console.log("---------------------------")
          const count = await staffRepository.count()
          console.log(count)
          console.log("---------------------------")
          //typecasting
          const page : number = parseInt(req.query.page as string) || 1; // Page number
          const pageSize : number = parseInt(req.query.pageSize as string, 10) || 10; // Number of items per page
          console.log(page)
         // const limit : number = 3
          // offset formula , here skip
          const skip = (page - 1) * pageSize;

       const allStaffData = await staffRepository.createQueryBuilder('staff')
       .skip(skip)
       .take(pageSize)
       .getMany();
//apply filter for isActive nd inactive 
      res.status(200).json({
        data : allStaffData});
 //      res.status(200).json({ data :allStaffData });
     } catch (error) {
       console.error('Error:', error);
       // Handle errors and send an appropriate response
       res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });  
     }
    }
```

My frontend code -->

```
// list-staff.component.ts

// Listing all Staff here --> 

 currentPage = 1; 
  pageSizeOptions: number[] = [5, 10, 20];
  postPerPage = 2

ngOnInit(){
    // automatically lists the staff
    this.listStaff()
    this.staffService.getAllStaffData(this.postPerPage, this.currentPage); 
 
  }

  listStaff(){
    try{
    this.staffService.getAllStaffData(this.postPerPage, 1).subscribe((data : Staff[]) =>{
      console.log(data)
      if(data!=null){
         var resultBody = data
         if (resultBody) {
          this.dataSource = resultBody
          // this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
         }
      } else{
        console.log("error in fecthing the staff")
       }
    })
   }catch(err){
    console.log("Error in get method :",err)
   }
  }
```

```
//list-staff.component.html -->

 <!-- Paginator -->
  <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions" showFirstLastButtons >
  </mat-paginator>
```

My staff service code -->

```
// staff.service.ts -->

// Read Staff Data Client Request-->
getAllStaffData(pagesize: number, currentPage: number) : Observable<Staff[]>{ 
const queryParams = `?pagesize=${pagesize}&currentPage=${currentPage}`
        return this.http.get<Staff[]>(this.getAllStaffURL+queryParams)
        .pipe( map((response : any) => {
                return response.data }) )
    }
```

Comment: I am a bit confused. Let me know if this is what you are expecting: You can provide both the amount of result and the current page and you are confused how backend will be able to know how much previous response was sent as you have a variable page size

Comment: @Chinz yes , i want to send the no.of entries and page number from frontend and backend should be able to comprehend and send the response accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In the backend, you should create a function to calculate the total number of results returned by the query and include it in your response. In the frontend, you will rely on this total number of results to implement pagination.